# Android Bundle NullPointer

Tags: android

In my Android application I want to transfer data between activities; mentioned FirstActivity.class and SecondActivity.class. But in my FirstActivity it is showing a `NullPointerException`. Can you tell me what's wrong in my class?

FirstActivity.class:

```
Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
         fingerPrintID = bundle.getString("ThumbInfo");
```

SecondActivity.class:

```
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putString("ThumbInfo", FingerImageData.toString());  
Intent enroll=new Intent(First.this,Enroll.class);
enroll.putExtras(bundle);
startActivity(enroll);
```

Comment: 11 questions and no accepted answers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose,,,If you pass data from activity1 to activity2::

In activity 1::

```
            Intent intent = new Intent(activity1.this, activity2.class);
            intent.putExtra("ThumbInfo", thumbInfo);
            startActivity(intent);
```

In activity 2::(in oncreate method)

```
            Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
            String category_name = bundle.getString("ThumbInfo");
```

Answer (score 0):

use

```
enroll.putExtras(bundle);
```

you have to pass the bundle with the intent.